# Jenkins and yarn install

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

For building my application, I have set up a build job which first runs `yarn install` to install all dependencies. However yarn crashes with this error:

```
yarn install v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/pinkie-promise/-/pinkie-promise-2.0.1.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "S:\\Programme\\Jenkins\\workspace\\choreappx_api_master-BC6HDZHDAXKRD2G5IJRIM5JRWMR24A5AH2QRJO273VHHXQFQQW4A\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

But when I open a PowerShell instance in the jenkins workspace and use `yarn install` from there, it works without a problem.

Does Jenkins execute scripts in a kind of sandbox which prevents yarn from properly connecting to the network? I know that the URL actually returns a 404 but again, I do not have the problem when running from PowerShell. Also tried with CMD, but no success there either.
Might this be a problem with using Jenkins for Windows?

Comment: Did you perform the manual test with the same user that runs Jenkins?